# Xamarin installed in visual studio 2015 and Android Emulator failed to load

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Xamarin in Visual studio 2015 and I have android and ios application within same solution file. when I am trying run android project in my local machine, I got error 'click retry to run the emulator in elevated mode. you do not have permission to modify internal Hyper-V network adapter settings,which are required to run the emulator'. So I clicked on "Retry" - it said windows packages changed to machine and I click on 'Yes', after that my local machine internet connection was gone. with the help of network engineer,Internet connection came back, my question is how can I run android application to my local machine without Hyper-V error.
I am a .Net developer and learning Mobile Application development, please can you help me out and suggest me that what I need to do?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You did the right thing by retrying emulator in elevator mode, That is supposed to create internal switches to run your emulator and set up internet connection for it. Shouldn't affect your internet connection.

I'll advice
1. Try running the emulator again and let it create the adapters as Visual studio android emulators run in Hyper V.

2. Test app with a physical device connected to your computer